# Combine 2 data sources in RxJava with possibility to fetch new data from 1 of the observables

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm currently working on an Android app where I'm using RxJava in a ViewModel to handle data from both a local Room database and a remote API (Retrofit). I have implemented a pull-to-refresh feature, and in the `onRefresh` method, I'm currently creating a new observable to fetch data from the remote API.

The problem is I want the combined observable to be triggered when user does pull-to-refresh, but it's not triggered.

What may be the issue?

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
    private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
) {

    private val remoteDataObservable = BehaviorSubject.createDefault<List<Data>>(emptyList())

    init {
        disposables += Observable.combineLatest(
            localDataSource.getData(),
            remoteDataObservable,
            { local, remote ->
                local.plus(remote)
            }
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                displayList(it)
            }
        fetchLatestData()
    }

    fun onPullToRefresh() {
        fetchLatestData()
    }
    
    private fun fetchLatestData() {
        remoteDataSource.fetchLatestData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(remoteDataObservable)
    }

    private fun displayList(list: List<Data>) {
        // Display list
    }

}
```

Comment: You can have a `PublishSubject<Unit>` that just signals that you need to fetch data. Then you `concatMap` or `switchMap` it by `remoteDataSource.fetchLatestData()`. You then take the resulting observable and `combineLatest` with `localDataSource`. So `combineLatest(local, subject.concatMap { remote.fetch }) { …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problem by changing a way to subscribe to the `Observable`, which fetches data from the API. Now I created a new subscriber, end emit data to the `BehaviorSubject` manually. I'm not satisfied with the solution, but nothing better came to my mind:

```
private fun fetchLatestData() {
    disposables += remoteDataSource.fetchLatestData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({
            remoteDataObservable.onNext(it)
        }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that your `fetchLatestData` method returns an `Observable`. I would suggest having something like this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
    private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
) {

    init {
        disposables += Observable.combineLatest(
            localDataSource.getData(),
            remoteDataSource.data,
            { local, remote ->
                local.plus(remote)
            }
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                displayList(it)
            }
        fetchLatestData()
    }

    fun onPullToRefresh() {
        fetchLatestData()
    }
    
    private fun fetchLatestData() {
        remoteDataSource.fetchLatestData()
    }
```

Your `RemoteDataSource` class would look something like this:

```kotlin
class RemoteDataSource {

    val data: BehaviorSubject<List<Data>>

    fun fetchLatestData() {
        // request the data from remote
        data.onNext(newFetchedData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, it would work, it's something similar that I wrote above. Here I see a problem, that if your DataSource have multiple subscribers, which are observing data and call fetchLatestData, it would be a mess, and we'll get an inconsistent state.

Comment: With your approach, you would need to always dispose the previous subscription, or else, whenever you'll call fetchLatestData, you would subscribe again to a new Observable and have leaks

Comment: Sure, thanks for noticing! I just didn't add it to my answer. Have done it now